# Expand abbreviation when the following non-keyword character is mapped to something else

Tags: key-bindings, abbreviations

I've got the following mappings and abbreviations in my .vimrc

```
let mapleader = ","
inoremap <leader>( ()<ESC>i
iabbrev pirnt print
```

Now abbreviations won't expand if the following character is an open parenthesis.

If I type:

```
pirnt,(
```

it won't correct my spelling mistake, and it leaves me with `pirnt()`

This seems to be the case for all mappings, for example I've got `jj` mapped to `<ESC>`, and if I type `pirntjj` it simply puts me in normal mode, leaving my spelling mistake there.

Not using a leader has no effect, either.

```
inoremap ( ()<ESC>i
```

produces the same result.

How can I make Vim expand abbreviations if the following character is mapped to something else?

Comment: Not sure it helps, but you can trigger the expansion of an abbreviation by hitting `<C-]>` (see `:h i^]`). So, maybe you could redefine your insert mode mapping like this: `inoremap <Leader>( <C-]>()<Esc>i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the abbreviation is not automatically expanded when you use your mapping, but you can manually trigger its expansion by hitting `<C-]>`.

From `:h i^]`:

```
CTRL-]      Trigger abbreviation, without inserting a character.
```

So, maybe you could use this key at the beginning of the `{rhs}` of your insert-mode mapping, to trigger the expansion of a possible abbreviation before inserting the parentheses.

It would give:

```
inoremap <leader>( <C-]>()<Esc>i
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `inoremap`. Try:

```
imap ( ()<ESC>i
```

Note the documentation at `:h recursive_mapping`:

```
[...] If the {rhs} starts with {lhs}, the first character is not mapped
again (this is Vi compatible).
```